# plot function in R with log scale parameters shows negative values

Tags: r, plot

I have a table with 2 columns: time and distance. Both they > 0 (in meters and minutes accordingly). When I do:

```
plot(dist, time, main="Distance vs Time", xlab="Distance (meters)", ylab="Time (min)")
```

I get following plot:
[image]

Not very readable. I will use log scale instead:

```
plot(log(dist), log(time), main="Distance vs Time", 
   xlab="Distance (meters), log scale", ylab="Time (min), log scale")
```

And I get following plot:
[image]

My question is: why plot shows negative values as well? I do not have any parameters less than 0.

Comment: The same reason why 10^-1 = 0.1 :) all values that are less than e has a negative logarithm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might prefer

```
plot(dist, time, log="xy", ...)
```

The reason you are getting negative values in the plot is that you have *explicitly taken the logarithm of your data*.  Values less than 1 will be transformed to negative values - that's just the way the math works ... using `log="xy"` instead will plot the points in the same locations, but will change the scales so that they show the original values.

```
set.seed(101)
x <- rlnorm(10)
y <- rlnorm(10)
par(mfrow=c(2,2),las=1,bty="l")
```

Plot on original scale:

```
plot(x,y)
```

Plot logged data, labeled by log values (which will be negative when the original values are <1):

```
plot(log(x),log(y))
```

Plot logged data, labeled by original values:

```
plot(x,y,log="xy")
```

Recreate the same plot (almost) from scratch by specifying the axis label ticks at the log positions but using the original values as labels:

```
plot(log(x),log(y),axes=FALSE)
brkpos <- c(0.2,0.5,1.0,2,3)
axis(side=1,at=log(brkpos),label=brkpos)
axis(side=2,at=log(brkpos),label=brkpos)
box()
```

(I should have used axis labels "x" and "y" in this last subplot rather than "log(x)" and "log(y)" ...)

[image]

Comment: This is the same as in the question (just a better way to do it). There is no error in the code just some lacking mathematical understanding

Comment: @BenBolker I do not understand why this inconsistency, log should give the same results no matter what.

Comment: It's just about how the axes are labeled.  See the updated version.